# progress bar in batch string manipulation

Tags: windows, variables, loops, batch-file, cmd

Here's my code, (i tried to make a progress bar but failed).
http://pastebin.com/JpUT3QvY
I get this as output: bar:~0,1 bar:~0,2 bar:~0,3 etc.. etc.. I want it to go like:`*, **, ***` etc.. basically increase the asterisk by 1 every 1 second.
Any help is much appreciated, i tried many different structures but failed.
Now i need to keep writing just so this filter can accept my question since it wants me to write more using proper grammar now you can stop reading as this is completely irrelevant to the question.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set bar=**********
    set cnt=0
    :LOOP
    cls
    set /A cnt+=1
    echo.Progress:!bar:~0,%cnt%!
    ping -n 1 www.google.com > nul 2>&1
    if "%cnt%" NEQ 10 goto :LOOP
    echo.finished.
    pause > nul
    exit /b
```

Comment: Your code needs to go here, and not off-site. It's unrealistic to expect us to leave StackOverflow, go somewhere else to see what you're actually asking, and then return here to try and answer you. Please [edit] your question and put the code in your question, and take the time to format it properly. The [help] pages have more information about how to ask questions here. (And if you do that, it will stop asking you for more, which means you won't have to waste our time with the noise you posted. Please abide by the guidelines here if you want to participate here.) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "bar=**********"
set /a cnt=0
:LOOP
cls
set /A cnt+=1
SET "progressbar=!bar:~0,%cnt%!"
ECHO(Progress:%progressbar%
ping -n 1 www.google.com > nul 2>&1
if %cnt% NEQ 10 goto :LOOP
ECHO(finished.

REM example without CLS
<NUL set/p "=Progress:"
:LOOPING
<NUL set/p"=*"
ping -n 1 www.google.com > nul 2>&1
SET /a count+=1
if %count% NEQ 10 goto :LOOPING
ECHO(&ECHO(finished.
```